# Rounded corners to table using tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to add rounded corners to my table in a react component using tailwind. I have tried using `rounded-lg` or any other rounded class to the component but it isn't working. What can I do?

```
"use client";

import { useTimeContext } from "@/context/TimeContext";
import formatTime from "@/utils/formatTime";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function LapTable() {
  const { stoppedTime, laps, setLaps } = useTimeContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stoppedTime !== 0) {
      setLaps((prevLaps: any) => [...prevLaps, stoppedTime]);
    }
  }, [stoppedTime, setLaps]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-5 mb-10 w-[540px]">
      <table className="w-full border-collapse border-gray-400 text-center rounded-lg">
        <thead>
          <tr className="bg-gray-200">
            <th className="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 w-1/2">Lap</th>
            <th className="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 w-1/2">Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {laps.map((lapTime, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td className="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 w-1/2">{index + 1}</td>
              <td className="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 w-1/2">{formatTime(lapTime)}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Use the border radius utility classes to make tables more rounded.

Comment: Have a look at this example here - https://preline.co/docs/tables.html#table-borders

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally add `border outline outline-1 outline-gray-400 overflow-hidden` classes to make this work

```
<table className="w-full border-collapse border outline outline-1 outline-gray-400 overflow-hidden text-center rounded-lg">
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table has a border, It will not give the desired effect by simply adding the `rounded-lg` to the `<table>`. To clip the border to rounded corners, you will have to use `overflow-hidden` class on the container div.

Then you can apply `rounded-lg` to the `<table>` element for the overall shape.

```
<div className="mt-5 mb-10 w-[540px] overflow-hidden">
  <table className="w-full border-collapse border-gray-400 text-center rounded-lg">
    {/* Other elemnts */}
  </table>
</div>
```